# How to add a table view to a navigation controller which itself is added as a childviewcontroller to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, childviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController added as a childViewController to a UIViewController.

```
exampleView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

//Setting the frame of the child UIViewController

CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 83.0;
frame.size.height = 200.0;
exampleView.view.frame = frame;

[self addChildViewController:exampleView];
[self.view addSubview:exampleView.view];
[exampleView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I then add a UINavigationController to the childViewController

```
//Adding navigation controller to the child view.

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]     initWithRootViewController:exampleView];
nav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
[exampleView.view addSubview:nav.view];
exampleView.title = @"mynameasdasd";
```

NOTE: I do this because I need the navigation controller to be in the center of my view (not occupying the entire screen size).

Now I want to add a TableView to this navigationController and continue with normal navigation. How should I do this. I am unable to add a tableview to this navigation controller.

Comment: You cannot add a table view to a navigation controller. You can only add a view controller containing a table view to a navigation controller.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I was adding a tableviewController.           navtablecontroller = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
 [nav pushViewController:navtablecontroller animated:YES]; But i am unable to see a tableview.

Comment: OK, I will write up the answer which you can then accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter you are passing to `initWithRootViewController` is wrong.  That should be the view of the `UITableViewController`

```
UITableViewController *tvc = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
tvc.delegate = <Put your UITableViewDelegate here>
tvc.datasource = <Put your UITableViewDatasource here>
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tvc];
nav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
[exampleView.view addSubview:nav.view];
exampleView.title = @"mynameasdasd";
```

Comment: I did as you said but I am unable to view the table. Can u tell any common mistake that i could make from the top of your head. I can see just the navbar. No table with it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a table view to a navigation controller. You can only add a view controller containing a table view to a navigation controller.